# Como posicionar a section abaixo do menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou utilizando menu Ancora, e quando clico no link ele fica com o início acima do menu, como faço para que posicione abaixo do menu?

Como fica:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como deveria ficar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

código:
´Script´

```
<script>
    var menu = $('#menu .nav li');
    var sectionPositions = $('section').map(function () {
        return $(this).position().top;
    });
    var sections = $('section');
    $(document).on('scroll', function () {
        var scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
        var currentElement;
        $(sectionPositions).each(function (i) {
            if (scroll > this - 50) currentElement = menu[i];
        });
        currentElement && addClass(currentElement);
    });
    menu.on('click', function () {
        addClass(this);
    });

    function addClass(el) {
        menu.removeClass('active');
        $(el).addClass('active');
    };
</script>
```

`Section`

```
    <section data-slide="4" id="Devices">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="div2 text-center">
                <img class="div2Img" src="~/Content/Images/BackGround/dispositivos.png" />

                <p class="div2Texto">Seu Site ou Software funcionando em qualquer dispositivo</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

`Menu`

```
<li><a href="#Devices">Dispositivos</a></li>
```

Comment: Comece por fechar a tag `section`...

Comment: Você pode adicionar alguns pixels em padding-top no seu elemento com a id "devices".

Comment: Tenta mudando a posição do menu pra absolute no css...

Answer (score 0):

Pelo o que vi você está usando menu com `position:fixed`, para resolver basta adicionar um `padding-top` no `body`:

```
body 
{ 
    padding-top: 60px; // altura do seu menu
}
```